# Why this Grammar rule is not matching in Yacc?

Tags: yacc

EDIT: the entire code. Now the problem is I have to use ':' in the goal production:
This is a code to generate the three address code for the toy c language :
It has 3 address code support for assignment, if and for;
the problem production id the if, starting with goal.

**EDIT**
my old lexer code :

```
%%


"if" return IF;
"else" return ELSE;
"for"  return FOR;
[0-9]+ {strcpy(yylval.dval,yytext);return NUM;}
{CHAR}+({DIGIT}*{CHAR}*)* {strcpy(yylval.dval,yytext);return ID;}

[ \t]+  ;
[\n]    return -1;
. {return yytext[0];}
%%
```

Yacc code :

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int yylex(void);
    char p[10]="t",n1[10];
    int n =0;

    %}
    %union
    {
    char dval[10];
    }
    %token IF ELSE FOR
    %left '+' '-'
    %left '*' '/'
    %nonassoc UMINUS

    %token <dval> ID NUM
    %type <dval> S E
    %type <dval> RO
    %%


    goal : IF '(' RO ')' {if_label1();} S ';'{if_label2();} ELSE ':' S ';' {if_label3();}
         | S
         | FOR '(' S ';' {for_label1();} RO ';' {for_label2();} S ')' {for_label3();}  S {for_label4();}  
         ;


    S : ID '=' E {printf(" %s = %s\n",$$, $3);}
      | E 
      ;


    E : ID        {n++;sprintf(n1,"%d",n);strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);printf(" %s = %s\n",$$,$1);}
      | NUM {}    {n++;sprintf(n1,"%d",n);strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);printf(" %s = %s\n",$$,$1);}

      | E '+' E {n++;sprintf(n1,"%d",n);strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);printf(" %s = %s + %s\n",$$,$1,$3);}
      | E '-' E {n++;sprintf(n1,"%d",n);strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);printf(" %s = %s – %s\n",$$,$1,$3);}
      | E '*' E {n++;sprintf(n1,"%d",n);strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);printf(" %s = %s * %s\n",$$,$1,$3);}
      | E '/' E {n++;sprintf(n1,"%d",n);strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);printf(" %s = %s / %s\n",$$,$1,$3);}
      | '(' E ')' {strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);}

    RO : E '>' E  {n++;sprintf(n1,"%d",n);strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);printf(" %s = %s > %s\n",$$,$1,$3);}
       | E '<' E  {n++;sprintf(n1,"%d",n);strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);printf(" %s = %s < %s\n",$$,$1,$3);}
       | E '==' E {n++;sprintf(n1,"%d",n);strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);printf(" %s = %s == %s\n",$$,$1,$3);}
       | E '!=' E {n++;sprintf(n1,"%d",n);strcpy($$,p);strcat($$,n1);printf(" %s = %s != %s\n",$$,$1,$3);}
       | E

    ;
    %%

    main()
    {
    yyparse();
    }

    int yyerror (char *s)
    {


    }
    if_label1()
    {
        printf("t%d = not t%d\n", n+1, n);
        printf("if t%d GOTO L1\n",n+1);
    }
    if_label2()
    {
        printf("GOTO L2\n");
        printf("L1 :\n");
    }

    if_label3()
    {
        printf("L2\n");
    }

    for_label1()
    {
        printf("L0:\n");
    }
    for_label2()
    {
        printf("t%d = not t%d\n", n+1, n);
        printf("if t%d GOTO L1\n",n+1);
        printf("GOTO L2:\n");
        printf("L3:\n");    
    }
    for_label3()
    {
        printf("GOTO L0\n");
        printf("L2:\n");
    }

    for_label4()
    {
        printf("GOTO L3\n");
        printf("L1:\n");
    }
```

output for the above code:

```
./a.out
if(a>c)a=b;else:a=c;
 t1 = a
 t2 = c
 t3 = t1 > t2
t4 = not t3
if t4 GOTO L1
 t4 = b
 a = t4
GOTO L2
L1 :
 t5 = c
 a = t5
L2
```

without the colon : ie :-

```
 goal : IF '(' RO ')' {if_label1();} S ';'{if_label2();} ELSE  S ';' {if_label3();}
```

output is

```
./a.out
if(a>c)a=d;else d=s;
 t1 = a
 t2 = c
 t3 = t1 > t2
t4 = not t3
if t4 GOTO L1
 t4 = d
 a = t4
GOTO L2
L1 :
wrong syntax  //which is not expected
```

I want to eliminate the colon after else.

Comment: I noticed that my rule does not match if there are spaces in between. How to allow extra spaces ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not matching'?  What input are you giving it and getting an unexpected result?  I suspect you have an error elsewhere in your grammar and are getting confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here from your comment that your lexer is returning spaces as tokens to your parser, which means that since your grammar doesn't have any space (`' '`) tokens, an input with spaces wont match anything.

The more usual arrangement is to have the lexer NOT return spaces -- just ignore them.  So you have a lex/flex rule like:

```
[ \t\n]    ;    /* ignore spaces, tabs, and newlines */
```

Of course this is just a guess, since you've provided no information about your lexer or what tokens it works with.

**edit**

You still haven't posted your lexer code, but combined with the following flex lexer, your parser works fine for me:

```
"if"    return IF;
"else"  return ELSE;
"for"   return FOR;
[a-z]+  { strcpy(yylval.dval, yytext); return ID; }
[0-9]+  { strcpy(yylval.dval, yytext); return NUM; }
[ \t\n] ;
.       return *yytext;
```

```
$ ./a.out
if(a>c)a=d;else d=s;
 t1 = a
 t2 = c
 t3 = t1 > t2
t4 = not t3
if t4 GOTO L1
 t4 = d
 a = t4
GOTO L2
L1 :
 t5 = s
 d = t5
L2
```

Comment: I made above changes, it solved some problem, like it now accepts 2* 3+2, earlier it just accepted 2*3+2, but it did not solve the colon problem. Posted the entire code as edits.

Comment: It works with your lexer, thank you so much,You solved my problem. But it wont work on my rather similar lexer I just posted, I am just wondering why ?

Comment: @Anubha: I think you need to return 0 from your lexer to indicate end of input at the newline, not -1 as your rule does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes you were correct, now it works with my old lex too :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The POSIX 1003.2 spec section A.3.7.4 says, `The end of the input is marked by a special token called the endmarker,
 which has a token number that is zero or negative.  (These values are
 invalid for any other token.)` which implies that 0 or -1 should be fine.  I guess it depends on which version of yacc Anubha is using.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Classically, a lexical analyzer indicated end of input by returning a zero token; empirically, changing from -1 to 0 fixes Anubha's problem. Consequently, we can deduce that the Lex/Yacc combination in use has not read that bit of the POSIX standard yet.  And, for portability, you are best off ignoring the 'or negative' option since it does not apply everywhere.